# How to check if printer is out of paper

Tags: linux, cups, printer

How can I check if cups printer is out of paper using commands only (no gui).

EDIT: Is it possible to check that using python?

EDIT2:
I tried it with different printer (EPSON TM-m30). When I try to print without paper it stuck in Processing.

`printer-state = processing`
`printer-state-message = Rendering completed`
`printer-state-reasons = none`

But I still cant get info about paper.

I am not sure if it can help you, I created json file from some python code which reads printer attribues: https://pastebin.com/u97U9TnQ

## Update

We bought another printer (Star Micronics TUP542), the printer has out of paper sensor: [Near End Paper Sensor](https://starmicronics.com/product/near-end-paper-sensor-for-tup-tmp500/), but I can't find any manual how to work with this sensor (sensor is plugged into printer). Does cups have some command for it? Or do I need to use some different tool?

I tried to get attributes using python, here is the result (json): https://pastebin.com/Z3Tiz5g9

BTW, *printer-state* is always `3`, with or without paper. Is it supposed to change when printer is out of paper?
I think *printer-state-reasons* should say something about missing paper, but there is always `['none']`

## Update 2

Maybe I should try ESC/POS commands ([here](http://www.starasia.com/Download/Manual/escpos_cm_en.pdf)).
I found some codes on page 157 *Transmission of status*.

> n = 1, 49: Sends paper detector status

But I am not sure what does mean `n = 1, 49` Is it string or decimal or hex values? Why there is comma between  1 and 49.

I tried this python code:

```py
command = [0x1D, 0x72, 1]
dest="/dev/usb/lp1"

with open(dest,"wb") as file:
    file.write(bytearray(command))

with open(dest,"rb") as file:
    data = file.read() # hangs
    print(data)
```

But read function hangs and never returns.

PS: I also tried different values (`[0x1D, 0x72, 49]`, `[0x1D, 0x72, 1, 49]`, `[0x1D, 0x72, 1, 0x49]`), but without success.

By the way, when I use `sudo cat /dev/usb/lp1` it prints lot of ###.

When I use hexdump after cat I see this repeating sequence: `23 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [lpstat](http://www.cups.org/doc/man-lpstat.html)?

For example, get a list of printers:

```
~$ lpstat -s

device for Canon_MX920_series: dnssd://Canon%20MX920%20series._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=00000000-0000-1000-8000-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Then query the print in question:

```
~$ lpstat -p "Canon_MX920_series"

printer Canon_MX920_series is idle.  enabled since Tue 18 Jan 2022 10:49:40 AM CST
scheduler is running
```

Comment: But does that report on paper out?

Comment: @roaima It will report printer failures should one occur.  I did not specifically check what happens when the printer is out of paper.

Comment: What does the `lpstat` command report if you manually remove the paper from that printer? Would it be the same for all printers?

Comment: when paper is out and trying to print something it writes `Sending data to printer`, but this is common message when I try to print with or without paper. But without paper message `Sending data to printer` stays forever.

Comment: @T0maas It seems you are correct.  Being out of paper does not count as a fault.  My answer will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the **subprocess** module using **Python** to run the **lpstat** command and parse the output to determine the printer's status.

Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
import subprocess

def is_printer_out_of_paper(printer_name):
    # Run the lpstat command to get the printer's status
    output = subprocess.run(["lpstat", "-p", printer_name, "-l"], capture_output=True).stdout.decode()

    # Check if the output contains the "out of paper" message
    return "out of paper" in output

# Example usage
if is_printer_out_of_paper("My Printer"):
    print("Printer is out of paper")
else:
    print("Printer has paper")
```

In this example, *My Printer* is the name of the printer, and the ***lpstat*** command is used to get the printer's status. The **-p** option specifies the printer name, and the **-l** option causes the lpstat command to list the printer's status in long format. The output of the lpstat command is captured using the *capture_output option* and is then decoded to a string using the ***stdout.decode()*** method. The string is then searched for the ***"out of paper" message*** to determine if the printer is out of paper.

Comment: The given code will say that any non-existing printer has paper. The answer also needlessly uses Python to run a shell command. The reason (I suppose) that the user wanted to use Python is because they believe they need to do something more complicated than to just use `lpstat`, but the answer does not consider the absurdity of running `lpstat` via Python.